# How to write a filter list method that works in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have this method:

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
      return obj[c] == criteria[c];
    });
  });
}
```

and I would like to write one that works the same and that works in Internet explorer 8 (that means not ECMA5 javascript I guess).

Comment: Look for polyfills for `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.every` and `Object.keys`. MDN usually have these on their pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often polyfill missing properties. E.g., `Array.filter()` can be implemented, when it's missing like shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i];

        // NOTE: Technically this should Object.defineProperty at
        //       the next index, as push can be affected by
        //       properties on Object.prototype and Array.prototype.
        //       But that method's new, and collisions should be
        //       rare, so use the more-compatible alternative.
        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

If you prepend this in an `IE8.js`, you can continue using above code.